# Deleting a file if it exists or not

Tags: shell-script, zsh, rm

Here is a part of my zshrc file.

```
## Most Frequently used settings
# ls
alias ls='rm .DS_Store; echo --------------${PWD##*/}--------------; ls -1FGu'
alias l='ls -A'
```

I want to delete .DS_Store, every time I ls, if it exists, but, if it doesn't, I don't want warning from rm.

Comment: I dont think this is a particular good idea to have a (typical) side effect free command modified this way. You could add a auto mount script, so this is done only once you plug a device in. But then again if a friend of yours wants to peek on his flash drive he might not be happy about losing his Apple settings. , but yes rm -f

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`rm -f` silences the nonexistent file warning.